# In node express with socket.io, why does my Content-Type header not include a charset value when loading the socket.io.js file?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, response-headers, charset

I have a node express server setup with socket.io. I had a question come up about why charset wasn't being set to UTF-8 in my response header when loading socket.io.js from my client-side html page. If I were to load it [in the socket.io demo page](https://socket.io/demos/chat/), I see the expected charset:

```
content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

In my app however, I see:

```
content-type: application/javascript;
```

(note: I need to do a hard refresh to see these headers show up in dev tools otherwise I just get a 304 no change)

Everything else in the app returns the charset header of UTF-8, so this leaves me scratching my head. Here's the minimal version of the app that can reproduce the issue:

help.ts

```
import * as http from 'http'
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'

let server

const startExpress = (): Promise<http.Server> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const app = express()
    app.use(cors())
    const port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000)

    const server = app
      .listen(port, () => {
        setRoutes(app)
        resolve(server)
      })
      .on('error', (error: Error) => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}

const setRoutes = (app: Application) => {
  app.get('/hi', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/hi.html')
  })
}

const setupSocketIoServer = (expressServer: http.Server): void => {
  server = new Server(expressServer, { cors: { origin: '*' } })
  // add events and such, not needed for this demo
}

const go = async () => {
  // start app
  const expressServer = await startExpress()

  // start socket.io
  setupSocketIoServer(expressServer)
}

go()
```

hi.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Getting it started:

```
npx ts-node help.ts
```

Since this is a module-provided file, I cannot seem to override it with something like:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (/.*\.js/.test(req.path)) {
    res.charset = 'utf-8'
  }
  next()
})
```

```
"express": "^4.18.2",
"socket.io": "^4.5.4"
```

I'm stumped. Any idea of what I might be missing?

Comment: You can't override the default serving of `socket.io.js` because socket.io inserts itself first in line so it can serve that without getting caught up in any of your Express routes.  You can disable the automatic sending of `socket.io.js` if you want by setting the `serveClient: false` option [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/).

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00. I would accept that in an answer with more detail. Not sure if this addition would be part off a correct answer, yet I was able to get it load with utf-8 via `serveClient: false` then adding `app.get('/socket.io.js', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.min.js')
  })` to express route mapping. I could also load via CDN as it turns out the socket.io demo page was doing as one option.

Comment: Why  do you need the `charset` value anyway? It's a script file, right?

Comment: @jfriend00 I think js file may need utf-8, e.g. for the alert message. But the thing is we don't need to set it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is you don't need to set `charset=utf-8` for js, please check [RFC 9239 Updates to ECMAScript Media Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239.html#name-common-javascript-media-typ), which was published in May 2022, the Encoding section says

> Module goal sources MUST be encoded as UTF-8; all other encodings will
> fail. Source goal sources SHOULD be encoded as UTF-8

I think the term **Source goal sources** there is **Script goal source** actually, as in Modules section says "In order to formalize support for modular programs, [ECMA-262] (starting with the 6th Edition) defines two top-level goal symbols for the ECMAScript grammar: **Module and Script**. The **Script goal** represents ... "

But why did you need to serve `socket.io.js` yourself, why not from CDN ?